# Custom post type split title, setup permalink accordingly

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, title

I am currently working on a project, where I need to do this -

- Create a custom post type called authors
- Create first name and last name field for authors
- Single author permalink structure must be first_name_field-last_name_field. e.g - author Arafat Jamil must have permalink arafat-jamil

How can I achieve this? Third party plugins must not be used, but you can name plugins, I can take the functionality out of it.

Comment: My targeted approach is to split the 'Title' field into two parts, that will create the first name and last name fields. If you have any idea, you can respond of course.

Comment: So you mean, a full permalink URL would look like `https://example.com/first-last/` (no base), or is it like `https://example.com/authors/first-last/` (base is `authors`)? What are these authors - authors of what? And as for splitting the post title, are you sure the author's name will always be `first last` and not `last first` or `first middle last`?

Comment: Authors, is a custom post type that I will build myself, it is not related to WordPress roles directly. You can think of this as a profile storage system, for example, you can consider a list of Employees. And I want to split the title with 2 different labels, First name and Last name.

Comment: Well by default, if the post title is `John Doe`, then WordPress will use `john-doe` as the post slug that's used in the permalink. As for creating the `authors` post type, you can use [`register_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/), and there are generators like [this](https://generatewp.com/post-type/) that you can quickly try. As for the first/last names, you can add them either as [custom fields](https://wordpress.org/support/article/custom-fields/) or terms in a [custom taxonomy](https://wordpress.org/support/article/taxonomies/).

Comment: I have already created a post type. I have also added meta boxes for other fields which were necessary. But If I can split the title, I won't need to work on the slug separately. If I take first and last name differently, I will need to change the slug again. Is there any way to split the title, may be in two parts of a form, and a third hidden field to connect the value of those two, before it is sent to database?

Comment: "*If I can split the title, I won't need to work on the slug separately*" - what do you mean by that, and what is the actual problem here that you're trying to solve? Are you saying that the title will always be the author's name (first & last) that's gonna be typed in manually, and when the post is saved, you want to split the title, and then auto-fill the first and last name fields/meta? If so, what's the point of having the first and last name fields?

Comment: I think I have found a new approach. It is setting up two custom fields, and set the title by concatenating the metaboxes. I am working on it, if it works, I will post it as a solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139879/discussion-between-arafat-jamil-and-sally-cj).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been working on this solution, I have come up with a different idea to implement this -

I have added two different meta boxes, one with **First Name**, the other with **Last Name**

Then I have hooked a function with `save_post_{$post->post_type}` hook like this -

```
add_action( "save_post_{$post->post_type}", "update_post_data" );

function update_post_data( $post_id ) {
    // Unhook to stop infinite loop.
    remove_action(  "save_post_{$post->post_type}", "update_post_data" );

    $fname = sanitize_title( get_post_meta( $post_id, '_first_name', true ) );
    $lname = sanitize_title( get_post_meta( $post_id, '_last_name', true ) );

    $post_title = ucwords( $fname . ' ' . $lname );
    $post_name  = $fname . '-' . $lname;

    $args = [
        'post_title' => $post_title,
        'post_name'  => $post_name,
    ];

    // Update post data.
    wp_update_post( $args );

    // Re-hook the function, to make it work in future.
    add_action( "save_post_{$post->post_type}", "update_post_data" );
}
```